# how to load images before other contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loading, preload

I have a website created using html.One of my pages contain some images which takes time to load. everything else loads perfect, but not the images. How can I load the images before every other contents of the page?

Comment: Look into using progressive loading. It loads a low resolution version of the image before adding more details until the image is fully loaded. There's really not any way to do exactly what you're asking for unfortunately.

Comment: You could add a spinner until rest of the content is loaded

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You could fake it but overlaying a white background div or something but the DOM will always parse first